# Pulling a file from SFTP server using partial file name

Tags: python, file, ssl, get, sftp

To obtain a file from a SFTP server I use the command:

```
sftp.get("directory/filename.ext", preserve_mtime = True)
```

This works fine when I point to the complete filename. However, there are files on the SFTP server that have a random code in their name together with a date. Can I search for a file in the SFTP directory using only the date part of the filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get a list of all the files in the directory and then check for the date in question:

```
targetDate = "01-01-2016" # Change to the correct format of course.
possibleFiles = sftp.listdir("directory/")
for i in possibleFiles:
    if targetDate in i:
        sftp.get("directory/" + i, preserve_mtime = True)
```

You can obviously then do further checks for the file's validity to make sure that it's the one you want.